# Java Processbuilder OutputStream

Tags: java, sockets, cmd

I am currently working on some kind of Remote cmd in java and i'm using ProcessBuilder to run the cmd Session. But i have the Problem that i can get the output of cmd but i dont know how to send Commands into the Running cmd Session so that they're executed.

That's my Server code :

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
                while(true){
                    Socket socket = server.accept();
                    new Thread(() -> {
                        try {

                        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
                        processBuilder.command("cmd.exe");
                        Process process = processBuilder.start();
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                        process.getOutputStream().write("dir".getBytes());

                        while(process.isAlive() && !socket.isClosed()) {
                            while(process.getInputStream().available() > 0) {
                                socket.getOutputStream().write(process.getInputStream().read());
                            }
                            while(process.getErrorStream().available() > 0) {
                                socket.getOutputStream().write(process.getErrorStream().read());
                            }
                            while(socket.getInputStream().available() > 0) {
                                System.out.println("input");
                                process.getOutputStream().write(socket.getInputStream().read());
                            }
                        }
                        System.out.println("EXIT");
                        socket.close();
                        } catch(Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }).start();
                }
```

And this is my Client code :

```
Socket s = new Socket(ip, Main.CMD_PORT);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
            while(!closed) {
                String line;
                if(s.getInputStream().available() > 0 && (line = br.readLine()) != null) textArea.append(line + "\n");
                if(buffer != "")  {
                    s.getOutputStream().write(buffer.getBytes());
                    buffer = "";
                }           
            }
            System.out.println("END");
            s.close();
            dispose();
```

The buffer contains the Commands that should be executed.
Now When i run both, i get the following output but i cannot run Commands.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.657]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.
```

Comment: `Thread.sleep(100);` is a code smell/anti-pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kind of fixed it by myself now. I needed to read the socket inputstream to an buffer and then write that to the outputstream of cmd.exe

```
try {

                        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
                        processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
                        processBuilder.command("cmd.exe");
                        Process process = processBuilder.start();
                        System.out.println("Console Started");
                        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()));
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

                        while(process.isAlive()) {
                            while(process.getInputStream().available() > 0) {
                                int i = process.getInputStream().read();
                                socket.getOutputStream().write(i);
                            }
                            while(socket.getInputStream().available() > 0) {
                                String line = br.readLine();
                                bw.write(line);
                                bw.newLine();
                                bw.flush();
                            }
                        }
                        process.destroy();
                        socket.close();
                        } catch(Exception e) {
                        }
```